# Encoding issue in .Rprofile at the startup of R

Tags: r, encoding, rprofile

I use R (v3.5.1) on Windows 10. And there is a `.Rprofile` file in my working directory. The file contains non-ASCII letters but is saved with UTF-8 encoding. At the startup, the encoding of non-ASCII letters is distorted. For example the code:

```
nth <- Sys.setlocale(locale = "Lithuanian")
print("Ą Ę Ė Į Š Č Ų")
```

if run at the startup results in:

```
[1] "Ä„ Ä\230 Ä– Ä® Å  Ä\214 Å²"
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to configure R that it sources `.Rprofile` with UTF-8 encoding at the startup?
2. Is there another way to get non-ASCII letters encoded correctly at the startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of possible answers:

R will source `.Rprofile` using the current code page. I don't know what encoding locale "Lithuanian" implies, but if you saved the file in that encoding instead of UTF-8, it might work.  (I'm not certain you can change the code page during an R session though.)

Every now and then I see that Windows claims to have a UTF-8 code page; maybe you can get that to work.

You could switch to a different OS that has proper UTF-8 support (Linux, MacOS, etc.) if that fails.

Maybe you could set up two files:  a pure ascii `.Rprofile` that sources a second file, declaring the second file to be UTF-8.  For example, put this in your `.Rprofile`:

```
source(".RprofileUTF8.R", encoding="UTF-8")
```

However, I have to warn you I couldn't get this to work.

You could use `\uxxx` escapes for the UTF-8 characters.  You can find those with code like

```
as.hexmode(utf8ToInt("Ą Ę Ė Į Š Č Ų"))
```

That shows

```
[1] "104" "020" "118" "020" "116" "020" "12e" "020" "160" "020" "10c" "020" "172"
```

so an equivalent string is "\u104 \u118 \u116 \u12e \u160 \u10c \u172" and for me,
putting this in the `.Rprofile` worked in a Windows session.

Comment: A reasonable guess of the encoding under the current locale is `localeToCharset()`. According to the session info at https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/311, the encoding might be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1257

Comment: Saving with encoding  `windows-1257` solved the issue.  Hex codes also did the job. I think, I'll prefer hex codes as this method seems more portable. Thank you, @Yihui and @user2554330.